# how do select all rows from table groups and count of contacts for each groups in sql

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:

- groups
- contacts

groups table's fields are:

- group_id
- group_name

contacts table fields are:

- contact_group_id
- contact_id
- contact_name

Now, I want to select all groups with count of group's contacts...

For e.g.:

groupname contacts count

friend 12 |
school 8  |
ennemy 0  |
family 25 |

i want all groups dispaly(include groups that have not any contacts)

thanks a lot

Comment: can you post sample data and output?

Comment: Please tell what SQL your talking about ? Microsoft SQL server, Mysql, oracle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do left join and then group by. Do following

```
select a.group_name, count(b.contact_id) from
groups a left join contacts b on
a.group_id = b.contact_group_id
group by a.group_name
```

See [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3f98a/3)

Answer (score 0):

Create a view containing the number of contacts per group and then outer join that view with your groups table.

```
CREATE VIEW contactscount AS
SELECT contact_group_id, COUNT(contact_id) AS count FROM contacts GROUP BY contact_group_id

SELECT * FROM groups OUTER JOIN contactscount ON contactscount.contact_group_id=groups.group_id
```

This selects Null for count of groups with no contacts. You could omit the view.

Comment: Why you are using view?

Comment: the output your query will return is wrong. He needs to return records even if there are no contacts. Also he needs name in output

Comment: thanks scraatz , but i'm begginer , and i can'r understant your code .

Answer (score 0):

SELECT  table1.group_name, COUNT(table2.contact_id)

FROM    table1 
        INNER JOIN table2 
            ON table1 .group_id = table2 .contact_group_id 
GROUP   BY table1.group_name

Comment: @user1971217 I have not verified it.

Comment: thanks , but this code only return groups that have contacts and other groups that have not contacts , no dispaly .